# Combine two separate georeferenced data sets in one table using CartoDB

Tags: carto, geocoding, timestamp

I have two tables each georeferenced in CartoDB with the same timestamps, can I merge the two and keep the georeferenced data so I have two sets of points but in one table?

Comment: Is this in PostGres/PostGis? If so, you can use a View I would think, or append both tables to a new table if it is static data

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to append the data, but not merging it, am I right?

You can do this by applying the following SQL query in the CartoDB Editor:

```
INSERT INTO table1name (column1, column2, column3) SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table2name
```

This will insert all your rows from table 2 into table 1. Notice that you need to use conveniently the column names (order is important too, do not include cartodb_id!).

In case you were actually interested in merging both datasets, you can just do a column join using a column you may have in common and selecting the_geom from the dataset you want to conserve it, but from you message I think you're interested in the append option.